# PGPool Config reload with watchdog

Tags: postgresql, watchdog, pgpool

I have a Master/Slave pgpool set-up with watchdog. I'm trying to reload PGPool config (pgpool.conf) file with some changes whenever a backend failover happens. I'm able to reload the config only in the pgpool instance that runs the failover script . Is there a way to sync this config across all pgpool nodes via watchdog or can this be done some other way?

Comment: I also have a similar requirement. If the failover script runs on the master pgPool will it get sync'd to the other pgpools ?

Comment: Yeah. possibly. But I cant ensure the script is always run on the master.